# Azure Functions: Is using gcServer recommended for consumption plans?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-function-app

I'm going through the list of [perf improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql) that can be made against `Cosmos DB`. My APIs are hosted in a Function app in consumption mode. Is turning on `gcServer` recommended for `Azure Functions`?

There is more information on `gcServer` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element).

> For single-processor computers, the default workstation garbage
> collection should be the fastest option. Either workstation or server
> can be used for two-processor computers. Server garbage collection
> should be the fastest option for more than two processors. Most
> commonly, multiprocessor server systems disable server GC and use
> workstation GC instead when many instances of a server app run on the
> same machine.

How many processors run in an active instance in a consumption plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many processors run in an active instance in a consumption plan?

Each instance of the Functions host in the Consumption plan is limited to 1.5 GB of memory and one CPU. So there is only 1 processor for that. For more details, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-and-premium-plans-work).